# What is the purpose of the Table attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the purpose of the Table attribute? How is it applicable in ASP.NET MVC 4? Are there any samples I could look at?

Comment: how about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute.aspx ?

Comment: I read it. But there is not a detailed explanation of this attribute.

Comment: What more do you need than "Specifies the database table that a class is mapped to."?